# How to delete a record if it has a parent_id assigned?

Tags: laravel

I have a categories table that allows to have subcategories through the parent_id.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I want to delete a subcategory. I get an error when I have a foreign key.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`doogmas`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `categories` where `id` = 30)
```

How can I delete the record even if I have the foreign key?

Comment: Add `onDelete('cascade')` here `$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: The problem when I put onDelete('cascade) is that it also deletes its parent, and I only want to delete the child (subcategory).

Comment: `onDelete('cascade')`  not delete the **parent**, it delete the child if parent has deleted.

Comment: If I delete a subcategory that has a parent_id, it automatically deletes the parent (the category). Why does this happen like this? I do not understand...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

to

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: The problem when I put onDelete('cascade) is that it also deletes its parent, and I only want to delete the child (subcategory).

Comment: try change `cascade` to `set null`. if it works, I'll edit my answer

Comment: If I put set null it automatically becomes a parent and what I need is to delete it, simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can set how your database handles it when you delete a row:

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: The problem when I put onDelete('cascade) is that it also deletes its parent, and I only want to delete the child (subcategory).

Comment: @Alberto no, it deletes all children if you delete the parent. If you don't want that, you can use 'set null' instead of 'cascade', That way, if you delete the parent, the childs parent id is set to null